# Patch process in Maven

Tags: maven, patch

Are there any best practices/processes to apply patch in an environment that uses maven to build artifacts? There are times when last minutes changes have broken things on the production.

We usually have a code freeze 2 days before release so that QA gets sufficient time to do regression and progression testing. After that if there are any fixes they go as patches on the server and are routed through the lead who reviews and notes these changes and are later checked in after QA has tested them.

But due to some manual issues I would like to streamline the patch process to avoid last minute issues.

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: That is more related to version control and a branching strategy than to maven. Do you use CI solutions?

Comment: Yes we use Jenkins here.